# Flowbite modals not opening again after using built in `show()` & `hide()` functions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using Flowbite modals to show sign up & sign in forms to the user. At the bottom of each of these modals is a button to switch to the other, e.g. "Not a member? **Sign up.**" or "Already have an account? **Sign in.**"

[image: sign in modal]
[image: sign up modal]

These buttons trigger an `onclick` event to the function `toggleSignInSignUpModals()` shown in full below:

```js
function toggleSignInSignUpModals(e) {
  // Hard coded these here for ease of understanding. //
  var currentModalName = "authentication-modal";
  var otherModalName = "sign-in-modal";
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var currentModalElem = document.getElementById(currentModalName);
  var otherModalElem = document.getElementById(otherModalName);

  const options = {
    placement: 'center',
    backdrop: 'dynamic',
    backdropClasses:
        'bg-gray-900/50 dark:bg-gray-900/80 fixed inset-0 z-40',
    closable: !0,
    onHide: function() {},
    onShow: function() {},
    onToggle: function() {}
  };

  var currentModalObj = new Modal(currentModalElem, options);
  currentModalObj.hide();

  var otherModalObj = new Modal(otherModalElem, options);
  otherModalObj.show();
}
```

In this function I'm using the built in Flowbite functions `hide()` & `show()` to switch between the 2 modals. Docs on these [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/modal/#methods).

This function works as expected when switching between the 2 modals. However, the modals both cease to operate after you've toggled between them and closed them (**shown below**):

[image]

**Note:** *It's worth mentioning at this point that the modals work perfectly when using them outside of this context (not using my custom function).*

For reference, [here](https://gist.github.com/ipg-only/ff080aec5c2119146d59b7da7bb8750e) is the Flowbite javascript being used.

- The `hide()` function can be seen on line `2191` [link to line](https://gist.github.com/ipg-only/ff080aec5c2119146d59b7da7bb8750e#file-flowbite-js-js-L2192)
- The `show()` function can be seen on line `2189` [link to line](https://gist.github.com/ipg-only/ff080aec5c2119146d59b7da7bb8750e#file-flowbite-js-js-L2190)
- And I think all the modal stuff starts on line `2106` [link to line](https://gist.github.com/ipg-only/ff080aec5c2119146d59b7da7bb8750e#file-flowbite-js-js-L2106)

---

**The main things I've tried:**

- I tried to instantiate the modals outside of the `onclick` function, to avoid them being freshly created every time a user toggles between the 2 modals. This resulted in the modals opening a second time successfully but then subsequently not closing properly (the modal overlay not being removed).
- I have a hunch this is something to do with how Flowbite creates and destroys `Modal` objects, and maybe I need to call additional methods besides just `hide()` & `show()`. So I've tried:

  - setting `isHidden = true` when hiding and `isHidden = false` when showing.
  - calling `destroy()` on the modal we're hiding.
  - calling `destroyAndRemoveInstance()` on the modal we're hiding.
  - calling `removeInstance()` on the modal we're hiding.
  - calling `toggle()` on both modals instead of `hide()` & `show()`.
- I also suspected this was to do with event listeners not being reset correctly using just `hide()` and `show()`, but looking into both of those functions shows that `_removeModalCloseEventListeners()` and `_setupModalCloseEventListeners()` are both being called.

---

**TLDR;** How do I get these modals functioning properly? :) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this (with a little help from the [founder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12877785/zolt%C3%A1n-sz%C5%91gy%C3%A9nyi) of Flowbite, thank you sir!).

In the `toggleSignInSignUpModals()` function: I was creating new `Modal` objects **in addition to the ones already present on the page**. This was causing the `show()` and `hide()` functions to be called twice for each `Modal` instance.

More specifically:

- On exiting the modals, neither instance had an `eventListenerInstance`, meaning no way for it to be opened again by the user.
- On exiting the modals, the last modal on screen before exiting was set to `isHidden = false`, further causing [this](https://gist.github.com/ipg-only/ff080aec5c2119146d59b7da7bb8750e#file-flowbite-js-js-L2154) line to fail within the function `_destroyBackdropEl()`.

Essentially, the modal states were all jacked up due to calling everything twice on each modal.

Here's my (working) code now:

```js
function toggleSignInSignUpModals(e) {
  var currentModalName = "some-name";
  var otherModalName = "some-other-name";

  var currentModalObj = FlowbiteInstances.getInstance('Modal', currentModalName);
  var otherModalObj = FlowbiteInstances.getInstance('Modal', otherModalName);

  currentModalObj.hide();
  otherModalObj.show();
}
```

Instead of creating new `Modal` instances, this finds the ones already on the page and handles them directly.

Again, thanks to **Zoltán Szőgyényi** for the help on this one!